# binary is able to run only when run after creating a symbolic link to it

Tags: c, linux, qt, operating-system, qmake

I am facing a rather strange problem. I have a 32 bit qmake binary placed at a very deep path. So for ease of use I created a link using

> ln -s /complicated/path/to/qmake ~/qmake

I am running a 64 bit machine. So I installed 32 bit libraries. The binary is failing to load when I run

> ~/qmake

it reports an error saying no such file or directory when the file is there.
but runs smoothly when I use 32 bit laoder

> /lib/ld-linux.so.2 ~/qmake

The more insteresting thing here is. If I run

> /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /complicated/path/to/qmake

it displays an error e.g

> qmake: @ɇ�: QRU�4�������̀]ZY�: H: Error 18446744073564424934

but as I have already mentioned the binary gets loaded using the symbolic link

so I have 2 problems here.

1. Why I have to explicitly mention the loader with the application
2. Why error with the complete path ... when the symbolic link is running fine ?

Comment: What does ld.so --list show in both examples ?

Comment: Note: Converted to hex, the error is `1999 9999 98BC 277D`. All these 9 digits is unlikely to be a coincidence, so the error value must have some signification.

Comment: @Medinoc can you redirect me to some useful link where I can observe the meaning of the error ?

Comment: You didn't say what happens when you run ~/qmake

Comment: @HamishMoffatt I have mentioned it now

Comment: @M.L. as I mentioned I use ld.so in one case ... here is the related output 
> /opt/mel/next+snapshot/sysroots/i686-melsdk-linux/lib/ld-linux.so.2 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf771c000)

Comment: why can't you use 64bit version of qmake at first place?

Comment: I am creating a package to ship. 32 bit qmake can run on all systems but 64-bit runs only on the 64bit ones

Comment: Run the commands (both working and failing variants) under `strace`. That difference in the strace output should point to the source of your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding #2, it may be the case that the original file path is longer than your shell or other operating environment can handle.